# How can group-adjacent - XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How can group-adjacent if the before year same text next paragraph then group move to descending order e.g.  `AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1994), AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1996)` and `ATPAC,` move to after this text `ATS Prods., Inc. v Champion Fiberglass,`.
**Input XML**

```
<root>
<p content-type="emLetHead">A</p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">A.M. v Albertsons, LLC (2009) 178 CA4th 455:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ABBA Rubber Co. v Seaquist (1991) 235 CA3d 1:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ABC Int&#x2019;l Traders, Inc. v Matsushita Elec. Corp. (1997) 14 C4th 1247:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1994) 23 CA4th 51:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1996) 13 C4th 1017:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ATPAC, Inc. v Aptitude Solutions, Inc. (ED Cal, Apr. 29, 2010, No. CIV. 2:10&#x2013;294 WBS KJM) 2010 US Dist Lexis 42109:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ATS Prods., Inc. v Champion Fiberglass, Inc. (ND Cal, Jan. 15, 2015, No. 13&#x2013;cv&#x2013;02403&#x2013;SI) 2015 US Dist Lexis 5106:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ATS Prods., Inc. v Champion Fiberglass, Inc. (ND Cal, Nov. 19, 2013, No. C 13-02403 SI) 2013 US Dist Lexis 13886:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Abadia-Peixoto v U.S. Dep&#x2019;t of Homeland Sec. (ND Cal, Aug. 23, 2013, No. 11-cv-04001 RS (KAW)) 2013 US Dist Lexis 120368:</named-content></p>
</root>
```

**XSL CODE**

```
    <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="named-content[@content-type='emEntry']">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:sort select="number(contains(named-content[@content-type='emEntry'], '(.+)\(([0-9]+)'))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected output**

```
<root>
<p content-type="emLetHead">A</p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">A.M. v Albertsons, LLC (2009) 178 CA4th 455:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ABBA Rubber Co. v Seaquist (1991) 235 CA3d 1:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ABC Int&#x2019;l Traders, Inc. v Matsushita Elec. Corp. (1997) 14 C4th 1247:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1996) 13 C4th 1017:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1994) 23 CA4th 51:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ATS Prods., Inc. v Champion Fiberglass, Inc. (ND Cal, Jan. 15, 2015, No. 13&#x2013;cv&#x2013;02403&#x2013;SI) 2015 US Dist Lexis 5106:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ATS Prods., Inc. v Champion Fiberglass, Inc. (ND Cal, Nov. 19, 2013, No. C 13-02403 SI) 2013 US Dist Lexis 13886:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ATPAC, Inc. v Aptitude Solutions, Inc. (ED Cal, Apr. 29, 2010, No. CIV. 2:10&#x2013;294 WBS KJM) 2010 US Dist Lexis 42109:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Abadia-Peixoto v U.S. Dep&#x2019;t of Homeland Sec. (ND Cal, Aug. 23, 2013, No. 11-cv-04001 RS (KAW)) 2013 US Dist Lexis 120368:</named-content></p>
</root>
```

Comment: "How can group-adjacent if the before year same text next paragraph then group move to descending order" I'm sorry, but I'm having real trouble understanding your English. And I don't understand why you're using group-adjacent when all the keys are different.

Comment: @MichaelKay Sir,Thanks for the reply I have solved 1st issue above the XML e. g. descending order `AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1996)` but 2nd issue is how to move `ATPAC,` between `ATS Prods.,` and `Abadia-Peixoto`. Please check my updated code (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to group adjacent elements on the substring before the `(` and then you want to extract the year to sort inside of a  group, here is an XSLT 3 sample using the `analyze-string` function (if you are restricted to XSLT 2 use the same approach but the `xsl:analyze-string` element instead inside of the function to extract the date):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:extract-year" as="xs:integer?">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:sequence
         select="analyze-string($input, '\(.*?([0-9]{4}).*\)')/*:match/*:group[@nr = 1]/xs:integer(.)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="substring-before(named-content[@content-type = 'emEntry'], '(')">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:sort select="let $year := mf:extract-year(.)
                                      return if ($year) then -$year else 1"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZXVFc

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the reply, 1st issue is OK but how to move `ATPAC,` between `ATS Prods.,` and `Abadia-Peixoto v U.S.`?

Comment: @Sandy, what are the criteria to group and sort these three items? For the other items it seemed to suffice to compare the first part before the `(` for the grouping and then to sort on the year but I don't understand so far what relates the three items in your comment.

Comment: Sir, I have found only one case long XML, if is possible with collation sort descending with comma or any other solution for this issue?

Comment: Sir @MartinHonnen `ATPAC,` we want group or sort 1st is Upper case if after 1st Upper words separate by `,` then move to down between `ATS Prods.,` and `Abadia-Peixoto v U.S`. after sort Initial case or camel case if it comes.

Comment: It seems you have a clear understanding of your sorting steps so perhaps just nest some `xsl:perform-sort` with the different steps.